# Create remediation script for deinstalling oracle java on every azure-managed client

Tags: java, azure, intune

while silently reading here for half an eternity, now comes the point where I´d like to ask a question.

We have been carved out from a big company lately and one of the endless things we have to solve is caring for sw-licensing.

However in this process it turned out that oracle is not a software company having at least a slight interest in senseful co-existing but a plain mafia-gang.
So after a few meetings with those self-righteous mobsters I just quitted and promised to wipe and extinct their SW from each server/client in order to not step in their criminal-licensing-traps.
While we already got rid of all oracleDBs, oracle java is still a problem also because employees keep installing it here and there not caring for consequences. (worldwide ~7500clients azure-managed).

So I want to come up with an remediation script looking for oracle java periodicly and deleting it.

While detection is working I cannot figure out why remediation is not working; So after two days of struggling around (I´m quite new to remediation methods and not a pro in powershell ) I´d like to know how you would do it:

Detection (works)

```
$MSICode = gwmi Win32_Product -filter "name like 'Java%' AND vendor like 'Oracle%'" | select IdentifyingNumber

if ($MSICode -eq $null){
    Write-Host "oracle java installations not found"
    Exit 0
}else{
    Write-Host "oracle java installations found"
    Exit 1
}
```

Remediation (Always prompts me with msiexec error asking for the right syntax while "write-Output $Deinstallcommands" shows the right values

```
$MSICode = gwmi Win32_Product -filter "name like 'Java%' AND vendor like 'Oracle%'" | select IdentifyingNumber

# Variable "Deinstallcommands" bereinigt die MSICode Variable ( + silent deinstall ) sodass sie wie cmd ausgeführt werden kann.

$Deinstallcommands = $MSICode.IdentifyingNumber -replace "{","MsiExec.exe /x{"

# Alle Deinstallcommands ausführen
 
#write-Output $Deinstallcommands

ForEach($IdentifyingNumber in $Deinstallcommands) {& cmd /c "$Deinstallcommands"}
```

Looking forward to your replies

Comment: Hi @Burdarper you are trying to execute all uninstall commands at once using `cmd /c "$Deinstallcommands"` . However, you should iterate over each uninstall command separately.

Comment: Hello Suresh,
thank you for your answer. @SureshChikkam

I guess this is what ForEach is already doing:

write-Output $Deinstallcommands is :


MsiExec.exe /x{71324AE4-039E-4CA4-87B4-2F64180391F0}
MsiExec.exe /x{4A03706F-666A-4037-7777-5F2748764D10}


Write-output $IdentifyingNumber after foreach only shows the first entry so this is already correct in my opinion:

If I copy&paste the $Deinstallcommands output manually in CMD is works and asks me whether I want to deinstall.

Comment: If it is done through &cmd /c via powershell like in my case it prompts me with wrong msiexec command spelling like described before.

Comment: Use this cmdlet `Start-Process` to execute the `msiexec.exe` command with the appropriate arguments.

`Start-Process -FilePath "$env:SystemRoot\system32\msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList "/x $IdentifyingNumber /quiet" -Wait -PassThru`

Answer (score 0):

> `ForEach($IdentifyingNumber in $Deinstallcommands) {& cmd /c "$Deinstallcommands"}`

- Actually, the loop in the remediation script seems to be incorrect, and you are using the entire array of `IdentifyingNumber` for each iteration.

```
# Detection
$MSICode = Get-WmiObject Win32_Product -Filter "name like 'Java%' AND vendor like 'Oracle%'" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IdentifyingNumber

if ($MSICode -eq $null) {
    Write-Host "Oracle Java installations not found"
    Exit 0
} else {
    Write-Host "Oracle Java installations found"
    Exit 1
}

# Remediation
foreach ($IdentifyingNumber in $MSICode) {
    $DeinstallCommand = "MsiExec.exe /x $IdentifyingNumber /qn"
    Write-Host "Running: $DeinstallCommand"
    Start-Process -FilePath "cmd.exe" -ArgumentList "/c $DeinstallCommand" -Wait
}

Write-Host "Oracle Java uninstallation complete"
Exit 0
```

- `Get-WmiObject`, which is a more modern and PowerShell-native way of retrieving WMI information and `Select-Object -ExpandProperty IdentifyingNumber` to extract the IdentifyingNumber from the WMI query resu    lt.
- I modified the loop to use each individual `IdentifyingNumber` in the uninstallation command and added `/qn` to the `MsiExec.exe` command for silent uninstallation (no user interface).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your efforts.
Was jsut trying your prevous suggestions, but instead of prompting for wrong msiexec parameters like before it just listed the following and did nothing else:

Comment: Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName                                                                                                                
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------                                                                                                                
      0       2      432       1632       0,00  33300   1 msiexec                                                                 
      0       2      428       1632       0,02  25396   1 msiexec

Comment: Testing your last suggestion now.

Two times a cmd window popped up and immediately vanished:


Output: 
'
Running: MsiExec.exe /x @{IdentifyingNumber={71324AE4-039E-4CA4-87B4-2F64180391F0}} /qn 
Running: MsiExec.exe /x @{IdentifyingNumber={4A03706F-666A-4037-7777-5F2748764D10}} /qn 
Oracle Java uninstallation complete
'


But oracle Java is still installed ( PS is running in adm mode )

Comment: sry I was trying to edit the textblock in a more readeable manner, but it doesn´t let me